# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have this following code:

```
int M = 3; 
int C = 5; 
int match = 3;
for ( int k =0; k < C; k ++ )
{
    match --; 
    if ( match == 0 && k = M )
    {
         std::cout << " equals" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But it gives out an error saying:

> Error: expression must be a modifiable value

on that "if" line. I am not trying to modify "match" or "k" value here, but why this error? if I only write it like:

```
if ( match == 0 )
```

it is ok. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Did you mean `k == M`?

Comment: You're lucky that it resulted in a compiler error due to the operator precedences of `&&` and `=`, instead of silently producing an incorrect program!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The assignment operator has lower precedence than `&&`, so your condition is equivalent to:

```
if ((match == 0 && k) = m)
```

But the left-hand side of this is an rvalue, namely the boolean resulting from the evaluation of the sub­expression `match == 0 && k`, so you cannot assign to it.

By contrast, comparison has higher precedence, so `match == 0 && k == m` is equivalent to:

```
if ((match == 0) && (k == m))
```

Comment: Can you list down some of the use-cases where assignment in the `if-condition` makes some sense

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Hmm, never?

Comment: @TMOTTM might cause some additional side-effects

Answer (score 62):

In C, you will also experience the same error if you declare a:

```
char array[size];
```

and than try to assign a value without specifying an index position:

```
array = '\0';
```

By doing:

```
array[index] = '0\';
```

You're specifying the accessible/modifiable address previously declared.

Answer (score 7):

You test `k = M` instead of `k == M`.
Maybe it is what you want to do, in this case, write `if (match == 0 && (k = M))`

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a single `=` is always an assignment in C or C++.

Your test should be `if ( match == 0 && k == M )`you made a typo on the `k == M` test.

If you really mean `k=M` (i.e. a side-effecting assignment inside a test) you should for readability reasons code `if (match == 0 && (k=m) != 0)` but most coding rules advise not writing that.

BTW, your mistake suggests to ask for all warnings (e.g. `-Wall` option to `g++`), and to upgrade to recent compilers. The next GCC 4.8 will give you:

```
 % g++-trunk -Wall -c ederman.cc
 ederman.cc: In function ‘void foo()’:
 ederman.cc:9:30: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
          if ( match == 0 && k = M )
                               ^
```

and Clang 3.1 also tells you `ederman.cc:9:30: error: expression is not assignable`

So use recent versions of free compilers and enable all the warnings when using them.

Answer (score -1):

For C programming, if you try to assign a string to a char array, you will have the same error.

```
char str[10];
str = "hello";  // error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

The right way is:

```
strcpy(str, "hello");
```