# How to store result of matrix multiplication (using a custom function which returns an array) in a different array (getting lvalue error)?

Tags: c++

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices. I have to do this multiplication a bunch of times so I created a function

```
float multiply_,matrix(float mat_1[R][C1], float mat_2[R][C2])
```

This function returns an array which I want to store in an array declared in main. But I get an error

> not modifiable lvalue

How can I store result of the function in a different array?

Function :

```
float multiply_matrix(float mat_1[N][R1], float mat_2[N][R2]){
    float temp[N][C2]; // temporary matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < R2; j++){   //since stress matrix has only one column
            temp[i][j] = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < N; a++){ //N here is the number of rows of the 2nd matrix
                temp[i][j] += mat_1[i][a]*mat_2[a][j];
            }
        }     
    }
    return temp[N][C2];
}
```

The way I'm trying to store the value in the main function:

```
float stress_12[N][R2];
stress_12 = multiple_matrix(T,stress_12);
```

I was expecting the array to be directly stored, but got an error

> expression must be an lvalue

I did understand what an lvalue error is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745601/expression-must-be-a-modifiable-lvalue), but I couldn't think of a way to store the result of the function.

Comment: You are going to be trying for a long time because **you cannot return arrays from functions in C or C++**. There are two things you can do instead, 1) you can pass a pointer to an array to the function that the function can use to 'return' the result. This is the solution if you are programming in C 2) You can do the sensible thing and use a vector instead of an array. Unlike arrays vectors can be returned from functions. This is the recommended solution if you are programming in C++.

Comment: ... and you can use `std::array` if the array sizes are known at compile time. What are the values of `N`, `R1`, `R2` and `C2`?

Comment: And, as your error message is telling you you cannot assign to arrays either, arrays are not 'modifiable lvalues'. Of course you can assign to array elements, but you cannot assign the array as a whole using `=`. Basically arrays are broken which is why as a C++ programmer you should be using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: If you wrapped your array in a struct `struct ArrayWrapper { float stress_12[N]{R2]; };` and passed and returned `ArrayWrapper`, then most of your issues go away.  You can assign `ArrayWrapper`, return `ArrayWrapper`, pass `ArrayWrapper`, etc.  The only thing different is that you access the inner array by using `.`, since it is a member variable of `ArrayWrapper`.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341472/returning-a-2d-arrray-in-c/49342542#49342542)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If that is a possibility (which I think it probably is) then the `std::array` option would also work, and I would argue be preferable on account of `std::array` giving additional functionality compared to `ArrayWrapper`.

Comment: @john -- Just in case there is the "you can't use STL" requirement that is imposed on so many students these days, might as well show how to thwart it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Fair point, although the kind of professor who would say no STL, would also take marks off because 'you didn't do it my way'.

Comment: @john -- If the student learned about `struct`, they could say "hey, you taught us struct, and I found out that sticking an array inside of it just worked".  Makes the case of putting the pieces together that were already taught, I guess.

Comment: @john I used vector but I'm still getting the same error with 2 more errors(no operator "=" and "*" matches these operands(2 distinct errors for both the operands, one in tem[i][j] = 0 and one in multiplication line). Also, should I now assume I cannot write `stress_12 = matrix_multiply(T,stress_xy)`, like this is a fundamentally wrong statement? (like I am missing something here?) Also, will it be better to use a pointer? like returning the address from the multiply function and storing it in another variable to access the values??

Comment: @VooDooDarkMagic No `stress_12 = matrix_multiply(T,stress_xy)` is a perfectly normal statement, one of the points of vectors is that you **can** write natural code like that. And no, there is no reason to use pointers. I'm afraid I can't speak to your errors without seeing the code that produces them. Give typical newbie mistakes though I would guess that you are overcomplicating, and will overcomplicate some more in order to try and fix things (thinking that pointers  might solve your problems is an example of that).

Comment: @john In terms of changes, I just changed, `float` to `vector<vector<float>>` and the return type of the function is also `vector< vector<float>>`

Comment: Arrays are a product of a time when you had CPUs clocked in the kHz and RAM measured in bytes. As a result they are very simple and very, very feature-limited. You can do a lot with them, but only after wrapping them in something smarter, which is exactly what `std::array` and `std::vector` are doing for you.

Comment: @VooDooDarkMagic OK, that sounds good, so the mistake must be somewhere else. But again, I can't guess what that is, you need to show the code. Maybe ask a new question.

Comment: @VooDooDarkMagic Taking a guess, maybe you have `vector<vector<float>> temp[N][C2];`, that is wrong, thats's a 2D array of 2D vectors. Instead what you should write is `vector<vector<float>> temp(N, vector<float>(C2));`. That's how you declare a 2D vector of size NxC2.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a programming standpoint your code has a few breaking errors.
First of all, when declaring the multiply_matrix function, your arguments can't be mat_1[N][R1] and mat_2[N][R2] because N, R1 and R2 are not defined (and these arrays would be dynamically sized, which c++ doesn't allow, for that you need to make a pointer to an array such as: `float* array = new float[x] // x is a variable or constant value`)

Assuming you are going to hard code N,
you should declare temp like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float> > temp(N, std::vector<float>(C2))
```

Instead you should use std::vector which is a dynamically sized array so your function would look like this:

```
    #include <vector>
    //std::vector<std::<vector<float> > is just a vector of vector or a 2 dimensional array of floats
    std::vector<std::vector<float> > multiply_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float> > mat_1, std::vector<std::vector<float> > mat_2){
    //your code here
    }
```

Your function also returns a float (meaning one floating point number, not an array) so the return type should be a vector<vector<float> >(a dynamic array of floats)

And lastly, you try to return temp[N][C2] which is not an array but a float (N-1th row, C2-1th column) and stress_12 is an array (also should be a vector).

Hope this helps.

Comment: >because N, R1 and R2 are not defined

They are already defined in the code, I just didn't post them. They are small numbers for now i.e just 3 and C2 is 1. 

I did everything you said regarding vectors, but now I am getting 2 more errors,

1) no operator "=" matches these operands where I initialize temp[i][j] = 0
2) no operator "*" matches these operands in the multiplication line.

Comment: I made a big mistake, I'll fix it in a minute.

Comment: The main question is still there though. How should I write `stress_12 = matrix_multiply(T,stress_xy)` ?? Because this is still showing an error. Is there a certain function that I'm missing?? or should I return a pointer instead and store the address returned from the matrix_multiply function in some other variable and use it to access the values of temp?

Comment: If you declared everything correctly there should be no issue. Note that stress_12 also needs to be of type ´std::vector<std::vector<float> >´.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has multiple issues. I will assume that the matrix dimensions `N`, `R1`, `R2`, `C2` are known at compile-time. If that is not the case, it should be stated in your question. I would replace all occurrences on the form

```
float matrix[M][N]
```

by

```
Matrix<M, N> matrix
```

with `Matrix` being defined as

```
#include <array>

template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<float, N>, M>;
```

This has the benefit that you can copy your matrix, return it as a value from a function, etc. In other words, it works just like any other value be it a struct or an `int`.

There are a few issues with incompatible matrix dimensions in the function `multiply_matrix`. I would reimplement that function as a template function with the matrix dimensions being compile-time parameters. Note that I corrected the dimensions of `mat_1` and `mat_2` so that `mat_1` has as many columns as `mat_2` has rows and the result matrix has as many rows as `mat_1` and as many columns as `mat_2`. Any attempt at passing matrices with incompatible dimensions will be caught at compile-time:

```
template <std::size_t M, std::size_t K, std::size_t N>
Matrix<M, N> multiply_matrix(
  const Matrix<M, K>& mat_1, const Matrix<K, N>& mat_2) {
    Matrix<M, N> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < K; a++) {
                temp[i][j] += mat_1[i][a]*mat_2[a][j];
            }
        }     
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Also note that the last line is `return temp;` instead of `return temp[N][C2];`.

Then I can use it like this...

```
Matrix<3, 3> T /* = ... */;
Matrix<3, 2> stress_12 /* = ... */;
stress_12 = multiply_matrix(T, stress_12);
```

If you plan on doing a lot of matrix maths, you may want to consider using a good matrix library such as [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) instead of reinventing your own stuff.